# Can Google Analytics track raw data?

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I've never used Google Analytics (GA), so maybe this is possible.  But, a friend of mine had someone create a site for him for quite a lot of money.  Anyway, my friend wanted the guy to add another textbox & database field to track some data and the guy said, "We'll add the textbox, but we'll let Google Analytics track the data for you and give you a report."

Anyway, adding another field seems trivial to me...but the developer said GA is "the way" to do it.  Everything I see about GA seems to track how people get to your site and how they explore it...but doesn't seem to capture RAW DATA for you.

1. Does GA capture RAW DATA?
2. If so, how?
3. What widgets are used?

The reporting aspects of GA are awesome, but relying on GA for RAW DATA seems hokey to me.  Why let someone else capture data you should be anyway?

...thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had honestly never thought about it before, but GA event tracking is not a bad solution for a simple "database". It allows several values to be passed for categorization, labeling, "additional info", and numerical data. In the case of the text box (presumably with a submit button) the following code would work fairly well:

```
var textbox = document.getElementById('myTextBox'),
    submitButton = document.getElementById('myButton');

submitButton.onclick = function()
{
    _trackEvent('data-store', textbox.name, textbox.value, 0);
    // 'data-store' can be replaced with whatever category of data you want, for sortability's sake
    // the 0 can be replaced with any other numerical data you want - but it must be numerical
}
```

This should answer your first two list items, but I'm unsure as to what you mean by "what widgets are used". It should be some simple javascript.

Comment: I noticed there are other widgets available for use on the GA site.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it can do that kind of thing with [Event Tracking](http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/tracking/eventTrackerGuide.html) and [Ecommerce Tracking](http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/tracking/gaTrackingEcommerce.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Custom Variables** to track any data you want to be tracked. Check [Custom Variables](http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/tracking/gaTrackingCustomVariables.html). You can btu your RAW DATA there.